# Difference between ML,AI,Deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

Im developing android app fro groceries shop.
How can include or what way i can use ML, AI, Deep learning in my app.
Im just beginner to ML , AI , DL. IM developing app for engineering mini project. So that parallely i can learn both things.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: There are a number of compare / contrast definitions available with a straightforward browser search -- and they do not all agree.  We expect you to do this research before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AI** means getting a computer to mimic human behavior in some way.

**Machine learning** is a subset of AI, and it consists of the techniques that enable computers to figure things out from the data and deliver AI applications.

**Deep learning**, meanwhile, is a subset of machine learning that enables computers to solve more complex problems.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Zunaib's answer:

**Machine Learning** is a subset of AI which consists of types of algorithms that are able to **autonomously** calculate conclusions based on the given data. Where as **Deep Learning** is a subset of machine learning where we use different types of **Neural Networks** as algorithms.